# Type of sorting algorithm

Tags: sorting

What type of sorting algorithm is this:

```
private static void Sort(int[] array) {
   int a=0,b=0;
   for (int j = 1; j < array.length; j++) {
        int index = array[j];
        int previouse_index = j-1;
        while ( (previouse_index >= 0 ) && ( array [previouse_index] < index ) ) 
        {
            array [previouse_index + 1] = array [previouse_index];
            previouse_index--;
            b++;
        }
        array[previouse_index+1] = index; 
        printNumbers(array);
        a++;
    }
    System.out.println("for loop iteration "+ a);
    System.out.println("while loop iteration "+ b);
}
```

Is it bubble sort? or insertion sort? or something completely different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After eliminating useless code, renaming variables and formatting it:

```
private static void Sort(int[] array) {
   for (int j = 1; j < array.length; j++) {
        int value = array[j];
        int index = j-1;
        while ( (index >= 0) && (array[index] < value) ) {
            array[index + 1] = array[index];
            index--;
        }
        array[index + 1] = value; 
    }
}
```

Now it is easy to see, that in the inner while-loop big values rise up in the array (like bubbles in the water), hence it's indeed an implementation of the *Bubble Sort Algorithm*